# Put 2 extras in intent

Tags: java, android

I've made an intent and i've put inside 2 extras

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Options.class);
                TextView labelName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label1); // value = "Counter1"
                TextView label2Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label2); // value = "Counter 2"
                String lblNameDefault = labelName.getText().toString();
                String lbl2NameDefault = label2Name.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra(LABEL_NAME_DEFAULT, lblNameDefault);
                intent.putExtra(LABEL_2_NAME_DEFAULT, lbl2NameDefault);
```

In my other activity i retrieve the info from them like this

```
//Get name from the label
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String lblNameDefault = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.LABEL_NAME_DEFAULT);
    String lbl2NameDefault = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.LABEL_2_NAME_DEFAULT);



   //Set current name to editText
    EditText labelNameDefault = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.set_name);
    EditText label2NameDefault = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.set_name2);
    labelNameDefault.setText(lblNameDefault, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
    label2NameDefault.setText(lbl2NameDefault, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

The problem is that i receive to both labelNameDefault and label2NameDefault the result from LABEL_2_NAME_DEFAULT.

Can i only pass one extra?
How can i pass them both?

By default the value of labelName is "Counter 1" and the value of label2Name is "counter 2"

If i comment out `intent.putExtra(LABEL_2_NAME_DEFAULT, lbl2NameDefault);` the first label name is ok.
It looks like LABEL_2_NAME_DEFAULT is overwriting LABEL_NAME_DEFAULT

Comment: My guess is you are adding same value for both extras. Post some extra code if possible.

Comment: I think @thinksteep is on the right track; also, what are the values of `LABEL_NAME_DEFAULT` and `LABEL_2_NAME_DEFAULT`?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a 'bundle' of extras rather than individual extras if you like, for example:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("LABEL_NAME_DEFAULT",lblNameDefault);
extras.putString("LABEL_2_NAME_DEFAULT",lbl2NameDefault);
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
Then in your Activity that your triggering, you can reference these like so:-

Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
String username_string = extras.getString("LABEL_NAME_DEFAULT");
String password_string = extras.getString("LABEL_2_NAME_DEFAULT");
Or (if you prefer):-

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String username_string = extras.getString("LABEL_NAME_DEFAULT");
String password_string = extras.getString("LABEL_2_NAME_DEFAULT");

Hope this helps! :-)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass two (or more) extras in an intent. You need to make sure that `LABEL_2_NAME_DEFAULT` and `LABEL_NAME_DEFAULT` does not have the same value, though.

Comment: They are not the same, LABEL_2_NAME_DEFAULT overwrites my LABEL_NAME_DEFAULT in some way

Answer (score 0):

activity one

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Options.class);
            TextView labelName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label1); // value = "Counter1"
            TextView label2Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label2); // value = "Counter 2"
            String lblNameDefault = labelName.getText().toString();
            String lbl2NameDefault = label2Name.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra("LABEL_NAME_DEFAULT", lblNameDefault);
            intent.putExtra("LABEL_2_NAME_DEFAULT", lbl2NameDefault);
```

activity two

```
 username_string = getIntent().getExtras().getString("LABEL_NAME_DEFAULT");
 password_string = getIntent().getExtras().getString("LABEL_2_NAME_DEFAULT");
```