# How can I share all items in an array using Intent?

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, share

I have a question. How can I share all items in an array using Intent to be shared in the Java language for Android? Because I have many items in the Array, in the example below I only put 2, but there are dozens.

Here's my code:

```
    String[] pe_Contra = {
            "Adalberto Cavalcanti",
            "Augusto Coutinho",
    };

    String[] pe_Contra_partido = {
            "PTB",
            "SD",
    };

    String[] pe_Contra_ComoVotou = {
            "Contra a Denúncia.",
            "Contra a Denúncia.",
        };


 botaoCompartilhar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, pe_Contra, pe_Contra_partido,  pe_Contra_ComoVotou);
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(sendIntent);
            }
        });
```

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429036/passing-string-array-between-android-activities

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing string array between android activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429036/passing-string-array-between-android-activities)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this use **[Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)** to pass String array with intent

use below code to send String array

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putStringArray("data1", pe_Contra);
b.putStringArray("data2", pe_Contra_partido);
b.putStringArray("data3", pe_Contra_ComoVotou);
Intent sendIntent=new Intent(this, OTherActivity.Class);
sendIntent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

to receive it in other activity use this

```
Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
String[] array1=b.getStringArray("data1");
String[] array2=b.getStringArray("data2");
String[] array3=b.getStringArray("data3");
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass arrays one by one using different keys as below:

```
sendIntent.putExtra("data1", pe_Contra);
sendIntent.putExtra("data2", pe_Contra_partido);
sendIntent.putExtra("data3", pe_Contra_ComoVotou);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to know how to put more than 1 extra with Bundle or just with many putExtras:
[Put 2 extras in intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804766/put-2-extras-in-intent)
and make one of the bundle items a count to know what is the size of the array. use a loop to build and read your Bundle according to the array size.